# Income requirements for Botswana residence permit

Tags: residency

Several web searches have failed to answer the question.  For a Botswana residence permit, one requirement is proof of sufficient support.  But how much do they consider "sufficient"?

Experience elsewhere suggests the amount is not necessarily realistic.  For example, I lived in Spain on MUCH less than the required "IPREM*4."